# How to detect if the user exited page edit mode?

Tags: development, visual-web-part, pages, postback

I am making a visual web part for SP2010, and the webpart hides shows content depending on if there was a postback or not. However the only exception to this, is the postback of exiting the page edit mode.

Is there a c# code that I can use to detect when the user has just checked in, or published the page during the postback? Basically a way to get the boolean value on page load that is true when the user checked in or published.

Does anyone know?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the real objective? As far as I know there is no easy way of, from a webpart knowing if the page (list item) has just been published or checked in.

You can use the following code to check if the page is in display or edit mode and take some action:

```
if (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Display)
  {
   // your code to support display mode
  }
  else //     Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode = SPControlMode.Edit
  {
   // your code to support edit mode
  }
```

Not sure if this is helpful in your scenario though.
Maybe you can save the last value and compare it to the current value on a post back to see if the user has just left edit mode!

Comment: I did some research, and saw this page: http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2005/03/11/1886.aspx. I am thinking that if I can get the name of the postback status, and see what it is for "clicked checked in or publish". Then I might be able to tell.

Comment: It seems by using `Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");`, the value from that is `ctl00$WebPartAdder` when u added the webpart, and 
`aspnetForm` when you click close, and empty string when its a postback from your own control.